# Android Opengl ES 3.0 Pixel Buffer Object And glReadPixel

Tags: android, glreadpixels, opengl-es-3.0, pbo

I want to improve glReadPixels() performance using PBO(for Android 4.3+), As glReadPixels takes about 30~50ms(1280*960) for each frame in my test device.But I can't use glReadPixels directly in Java, since the last param cannot be zero or "null". I also try to use ndk as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570710/android-opengl-es-3-0-pbo-instead-of-glreadpixels). But the last param needs to be (void*) either in my ndk's GLES3/gl3.h. So the question is how can I use glReadPixels to make PBO work? Is this the right solution for better performance?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast the last parameter from int to void* explicitly in your c++ codes.